# change json values using jq in ubuntu linux machine

Tags: json, ubuntu, jq

I have a json file as example.json

```
 [
  {
    "node": "cp-phix-app-uat14.hcinternal.net:80",
    "priority": 1,
    "state": "draining",
    "weight": 1
  },
  {
    "node": "cp-phix-app-uat13.hcinternal.net:80",
    "priority": 1,
    "state": "active",
    "weight": 1
  }
]
```

I want to make a query using jq where if my node key is "cp-phix-app-uat14.hcinternal.net:80" then put state as "active' so my output should be like :-

```
 [
  {
    "node": "cp-phix-app-uat14.hcinternal.net:80",
    "priority": 1,
    **"state": "active",**
    "weight": 1
  },
  {
    "node": "cp-phix-app-uat13.hcinternal.net:80",
    "priority": 1,
    "state": "active",
    "weight": 1
  }
]
```

What query i can make.. i am using linux ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
map( if .node ==  "cp-phix-app-uat14.hcinternal.net:80"
     then .state = "active"
     else .
     end )
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43468426/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @Dev-iL -- The problem is elementary, and the answer is short and simple enough to be a guide to what needs to be understood (here, `map` and `=`).  `map` and assignment are common enough concepts, and the jq documentation is readily available for specific details.  Given that the OP did not post an attempt to solve the problem, providing some pointers in the form of an answer seems a reasonable response.

Comment: Additional context for this answer would be useful to explain how and why it answers the question.